# Definition of Hall's current

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Dear fellow physicists!

I come to you with a question regarding the definiton of the Hall current.
The only sentence close to definition of this concept, I have found after extensive search on the internet was the book "Hall Effect Devices" by Popovic.
Popovic says only this: "We shall see that this change in the terminal currents is related to the so-called Hall current. The Hall current can also be regarded as the output signal of a Hall device. "
It's the closest sentence to definition I have found, but still is insufficient. Could you provide me wither with the definition or with a resource with the definition of this concept?
I'm working on the dissipation of the Hall's current (but this concept is not important for this question).
I'm working with Hall's effect in Semiconductors (with only n type of carriers) - primarly with ideal Hall's Bar and Corbino disk. Plasma physics is out of my interest range.
I already know the "Generalized Ohm's Law", my searchings are rather definitional - I have found papers and books talking about Hall's Current without properly defining what is this thing, hence I'm looking for a definition of it.

Comment: Start with the Hall effect voltage. The Hall current is driven by that voltage.

Comment: I have already started with Hall's voltage, the question I have is more "in depth" - due to the lack of better wording.
Not neccesarily - in the case of Corbino's disk, there's no transverse voltage, yet there is transverse Hall's current.

Answer (score 0):

The Hall effect is a consequence of the magnetic Lorentz force term q(vxB) on an electron moving with mean velocity v in an electric field (v and B are vectors). It thus seems fitting to call "Hall current" the current density vector component due to the magnetic force term jH = n*q(vxB) (with n = electron concentration) which according to this vector product is vertical to both the mean electron drift velocity v and the magnetic field. In the Corbino disk, this leads to the spiraling current field lines in spite of the radial electric field. In the usual Hall voltage measurement, this current is internally compensated by the transverse electric current due to the Hall voltage.

There is a recent JAP article entitled "The physical properties of the Hall current", which gives a definition of the Hall current. You will find it here: [F. Faisant, et al., J. Appl. Phys. 129, 144501 (2021]. This , however, refers to Hall devices with an external current "Hall current". [1](https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0044912)

You might get a better definition in one of the older  monographs on galvanomagnetic effects. For example:
A.C. Beer, Galvanomagnetic Effects in Semiconductors, New York, Academic Press 1963. I have seen this book long time ago, but have no library access to it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a slight misunderstanding regarding the Hall current. The Hall effect itself doesn't generate a current within the material, but rather a voltage across it. This voltage, called the Hall voltage (VH), is what the Hall device measures.

Here's a breakdown:

```
Hall Effect: When a current-carrying conductor (semiconductor in your case) is placed in a magnetic field perpendicular to the current flow, the moving charges experience a force (Lorentz force) that pushes them towards one edge of the conductor. This creates an accumulation of charge carriers on one side and a depletion region on the other, resulting in a potential difference (voltage) – the Hall voltage.

Hall Current (Misconception): There's no actual current flow within the conductor due to the Hall effect. The accumulated charges create the voltage, but they don't complete a circuit and flow as a current.
```